# Automatic page break using laravel + mpdf

Tags: php, css, laravel, vue.js, mpdf

I am trying to automatically page break if the data is more than 10 Im using mpdf + laravel + vue

This is my css code

```
  <style>
div.breakNow { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always; }
</style>
```

This is my sale_pdf.blade.php

```
    $i=0;
         @foreach ($details as $detail)
         $i++;
         if( $i % 10 == 0 ){

<div class="breakNow">
             <div id="details_inv">
                <table  class="table-sm">
                   <thead>
                      <tr>
                         <th>PRODUCT</th>
                         <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
                         <th>QUANTITY</th>
                         <th>DISCOUNT</th>
                         <th>TAX</th>
                         <th>TOTAL</th>
                      </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
    
                
                      <tr>
                         <td>{{$detail['code']}} ({{$detail['name']}})</td>
                         <td>{{$detail['price']}} </td>
                         <td>{{$detail['quantity']}}/{{$detail['unitSale']}}</td>
                         <td>{{$detail['DiscountNet']}} </td>
                         <td>{{$detail['taxe']}} </td>
                         <td>{{$detail['total']}} </td>
                      </tr>
                   }  @endforeach
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </div>
           </div>
```

This is the current output.

[image]

Did I missed something? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way you can resolve this.

**Option 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2**
Adding class between table row

```
$i=0;
@foreach ($details as $detail)
  $i++;

<div class="{{ ( $i % 10 == 0 ) ? 'breakNow':''}}"></div>
@endforeach
```